# Header value inside AngularJS error callback

Tags: angularjs, spring, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

Angular save

```
            Model.save(obj, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
            var onSaveError = function(res)
            {

            };

            var onSaveSuccess = function(res)
            {

            };
```

Spring code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/models", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Model> updateModel(@RequestBody Model model) 
........
return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert("Failure", "I am here")).body(null);
}
```

is there any possibility i can get `"I am here"` string send by spring in `Angular onSaveError callback`

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by myself.

```
            var onSaveError = function(res)
            {
                var header = res.headers("Failure");
            };
```